# How to use the word "lucky" properly?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, exclamatives

Imagine i'm walking in the street starting looking for a florist and i come across one straightaway. Should I say or think: "How lucky!" or rather "How lucky for me! or How lucky I am? Is there any other phrase that would be more appropriate and colloquial to say in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How lucky!" sounds a little bit old-fashioned or overly-dramatic.

"That was lucky!" or "that's lucky!" would probably be the most natural-sounding.

(Upon immediately finding something "lucky" it doesn't really matter too much whether you use the past or present tense, as you could either be referring to the event that has just happened or commenting on your present situation)

Comment: Why is the phrase in the past tense, why not in the present tense like:" That's lucky!" in the sense of "That is lucky!"

Comment: @zenith3 The tense doesn't matter too much, as you could be commenting on finding the florist (which has already happened, so arguably in the past) or your present situation (as you are still at the florist).